# C++ Lockless Threading Question - Multiple threads iterating over a contiguous array but never accessing same member data?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, jobs, lockless

In my C++ game engine, I have a job system which utilizes worker threads to do various tasks. Threads are affinitized to each available core. Recently, I have been trying to optimize some of my system pipelines by maximizing CPU utilization. Here is some example pseudo-ish code. It isn't an exact replica but the situation is similar.

```
struct entityState {
  uint8 * byteBuffer; // Serialized binary data for the Entity
  uint8 * compressedData; // Compressed version of Entity data
  uint64  guid; // Unique ID
  gameTimeMS lastUpdated; // last time buffer was updated in milliseconds
  uint32 numUpdates; // Count of the number of updates
  uint32 numTimesAckedOverNetwork; // How many times client acked the data
  const char * typeData; // Type data in place of RTT
  bool markedForDelete; // Whether this object should be deleted next frame
  const char * debugData; // In debug configs, store meta data 
  // More member data but the point is made
};

// For examples sake, I have a contiguous array of entityState data
List< entityState * > entityStateList;
PopulateListWithEntityStateData(); // ~20,000 entityState ptrs on average
SortEntityStateList();
// Fire off 5 jobs each with their own worker thread
StartEntityStateJobs();
```

I then have 5 jobs that operate on this list at the same time with no **Mutexes** or **Critical Sections**. Each job function accesses the array via binary search based on a criteria, such as a guid, or just a linear search. Here is the catch. *None of the job functions modify the same member data of the entityState ptrs in the **entityStateList***. However, they can deference the same entityState ptr due to the binary search vs linear search having collisions. But, I repeat, they never modify the same member data at the same time. No member data ptrs are dereferenced at the same time on each thread.

I have run this simulation with a unit test and encountered no issues. However, I have some programmer friends who say there is a very very small probability this will cause undefined behavior with threads pausing and resuming when dereferencing the same entityStatePtr.

The other point I have heard is that the reason this setup has worked, is that the entityState struct size does not fit in a cache line and ends up dividing the data fetching, which in of itself, acts as data protection itself due to the struct data being separated into different cache lines. To clarify, let's say the top half fits in one cache line and the bottom half in another and the job functions only operate on one data member of the entityState ptr and the majority of the time it happens to be on a different cache line. I do not use any atomic modifiers or operations on the member data because no jobs touch the same member data.

Lastly, I also have some programmer friends who say this is perfectly thread safe.

Nevertheless, I have three different statements and my low level knowledge is lacking enough about multi-threading to ascertain which is claim is correct.

The question is... is it possible for a super low crash that could happen in the wild 1 out of 'x' times? Even 1/1million is not acceptable. Is this a safe, **lockless** threading mechanism to perform multiple operations on the list in parallel? Try to overlook the triviality of the example data. It is much more complex in my engine example. This code can run on multiple OS, such as PC, Linux, and consoles. It has yet to crash but the exposure and testing is limited. I admit I am not a low level expert, but this is saving precious performance time. So, am I waiting to run into a land mine or is this safe? Compiler is gcc version C++11. Also, please avoid the performance topic of locality unless its related to threading and or thread safety. I know cache misses are bad.

**The Question** - Is is thread safe or not? If yes or no please explain why in detail if possible. I would like to bolster my low level knowledge.

Comment: Is there a reason for a close and downvote? I am happy to reword or remove if you believe there is a duplicate. I feel like the cache line variance to this question makes it a bit unique.

Comment: Multiple threads reading the same resource shouldn't introduce a race condition, no need for mutex.

Comment: Apologies but this is much harder to find a correct answer to than you might think. But, if you believe its a trivial question, I am sorry.

Comment: (not down- or close-voter) Can you please clarify what exactly the threads do? You must assure that each member that is written to by one thread is not accessed by another thread without synchronization. It is not clear from your question whether such write may happen in parallel with reads or how you assure that two threads do not modify the same member potentially in parallel (this *always* requires some synchronization).

Comment: Job 1 - Gather byte data of entity for serialization -> next on chain Job 2 - Compress entity ptr data. Job 3 read in network packet data as it comes and ack the data. Job4 update the time and number of updates. Job5 - Update debugData. Apologies, this is a pseudo code example but that is essentially what is happening. Network packet data can come in at anytime. Also, there is actually a 6th job to update and merge unacked entityState. Debug and Type data is filled out on the main thread

Comment: @PaulRenton So the next job in this chain must wait for the previous one to finish before it can work on the given list element? If so, how do you assure this ordering?

Comment: The job system has a jobchain object which can guarantee order of job functions. But, it does not guarantee the same thread is used after the first is complete. When the first job finishes, the second job fires off with the same job memory passed in to both

Comment: Please clarify "*they never modify the same member data at the same time*". What is modified, by whom and when. You can safely have multiple readers if there are no writers, provided a synchronization took place after the last time a value was written.

Comment: None of the threads are reading. All are modifying member data variables of the entityState struct. They never modify the same member variable in any of the job functions. To clarify more, no job function ever dereferences the same entityStatePtr->memberVar. However, they can deference the same entityStatePtr to access the member data it needs to modify. So, no reading threads, all writing threads.

Comment: @PaulRenton And the search that you are worried about never accesses (not dereferences!) any of the members that the other threads might be working on?

Comment: Yes all threads modify different member data variables of entityState ptrs in the List. But, like I mentioned, its possible for threads to access the same entityState ptr at the same time

Comment: @PaulRenton The important part is whether "access the same entityState ptr at the same time" includes accessing one of the members of that object unsynchronized with another thread writing to it. For example if the search reads (the address) `byteBuffer`, but there is a possibility that it might be modified by another thread at the same time, there is a problem. Otherwise what you are describing seems to be fine. But it is always trickier to tell without actual code, because a mistake is so easy to make.

Comment: To be sure run your unit test under [ThreadSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerCppManual).

Comment: @walnut No, I made sure none of the writing threads never access the same member variable data. Nevertheless, I have some very experienced C and C++ programmers friends saying this has a possibility to be a land mind crash when accessing the entityStatePtr at the same time. This is where my knowledge falls short. This isn't verbatim, but some insisted the ptr being read into register may not be complete while another thread also loads it. Also, I was given the cache line statement that acts as thread safety in itself, which I found interesting

Comment: @PaulRenton Parallel reads without a potentially parallel write are always allowed. You must be careful when you use a container though, because you must verify that the container provides this same data race avoidance guarantee. There is a difference between what the standard requires from programs and what actual CPUs do. There are some cases that are data races and undefined behavior according to the standard, but may work out fine on actual common hardware. You should target the thread model of the standard, not some specific hardware to be sure

Comment: @rustyx Thank you. I did not know that existed

Comment: Then it doesn't matter at all how particularly cache or registers behave, since the compiler gives you the C++ standard guarantees for the code anyway.

Comment: @walnut the container is actually a simple C array with contiguous memory wrapped in my own array data structure. It can be static or grow in powers of two. When the jobs run, I do guarantee the array never resizes until all are complete. I get away with this by doing a TryWait before attempting to launch the jobs. TryWait does a fixed ms loop wait and if the jobs aren't done it skips the work for the frame.

Comment: @PaulRenton Accessing different elements of an array is guaranteed to not cause data races, as is access to different (non-overlapping, non-bitfield) members of a structure. Access to the same element (of either) is guaranteed to not cause a data race as long as all these unsynchronized accesses are reads. Also see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races) for a quick overview of what does and does not cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @walnut Yes I am aware of that with access and reads but what gives me pause is the jobs are all accessing and writing.

Comment: @PaulRenton But you were saying that the additional access is never to the same scalar object that is written to, right? That is the important bit. The whole memory model only is concerned with individual *memory locations* which essentially is the same as a *scalar object* (with the exception of bitfields).

Comment: @walnut that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@walnut already explained in detail that "accessing different elements of an array is guaranteed to not cause data races".

However, you mentioned that you have multiple job functions updating the entityState, and that these functions are ordered by some jobchain object. You did not go into detail about how this jobchain is implemented, but you have to ensure that it establishes a proper *happens-before* relation between the different job functions, otherwise you *do* have a data race on the *entiyState members*.

And I also agree with @rustyx - run your code with ThreadSanitizer. It helps unveil a lot of threading issues, including data races.

Comment: There is a proper happens before relationship. Sorry if it wasn't clear in the comments. I believe the answer and details are all cleared up. As long as the threads do not alter the same member data of the entityStatePtr's during parallel async processes (with some exceptions IE: bit changes), that the current setup is safe for lockless threading.

Comment: On another note, if you code is pretty much guaranteed not to need locks, having the locks there is not very expensive.  Locking a mutex without contention on the mutex is not costly, and neither is unlocking it.  When there will be no contention on the locks, as is your case (you think), it can be cheap insurance to do the locking.  This gives you protection against changes in the future that might require the locks.

Comment: @ttemple I have observed this as well with performance profiling. I always assumed Mutex calls involve OS calls though?

Comment: @Paul Renton - I don't know the exact implementation details.  I have learned the hard way that guaranteed behavior outweighs the cost of few extra instructions to do the locking.  If you use standard compliant code you will get defined behavior regardless of platform details.  If you obviously don't need the locks, no problem leaving them out, but I have never found locks to be my performance bottleneck.

Comment: @ttemple Yeah I am still learning as well. Code has to work on almost all modern game platforms: IE: Windows, PS4, Xbox, Linux, etc.. If you know any good resources for C++ threading, let me know. I do try to avoud stl as much as possible though

Comment: @PaulRenton if you are looking for some concurrent/lock-free data structures I can recommend my [xenium](https://github.com/mpoeter/xenium) library. It works on Windows and Linux, but I don't know about PS4/Xbox - would be very interesting though!

Comment: @mpoeter I will check it out!